# Rsync files that contain today's date

Tags: bash, cron, rsync

I need to rsync some files from a remote box. the files are in a folder

```
/logs/
    A/
        log_x_20170101_abc.txt
        log_x_20170102_abc.txt
        log_x_20170103_abc.txt
        log_y_20170101_abc.txt
        log_y_20170102_abc.txt
        ....
    B/
        log_x_20170101_def.txt
        log_x_20170102_def.txt
```

and I need to cron a rsync on a daily basis that only copies the files that contain today's date as well as the folder structure. Any suggestion on how to set this up?

Comment: `man rsync` -> search for `include`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync /logs/A/log_*_`date +%Y%d%m`_abc.txt /logs/B
```

Not sure what you mean by folder structure as you dont really show us any folders outside of the source and destination directory.